# How to wrap all divs expect one div which have a .header-container-wrapper class?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hubspot

I am working with a project with `hubspot`, here I am getting a problem where I want to wrap all the `div` inside the `body` element expect the the `div` which have `.header-container-wrapper` class,  I am using bellow default code provided by the `hubspot` which use for wrap all the `divs` whith `#site-wrapper`

```
$('body> div').find('script:not(script[type="IN/Share"])').remove().end().wrapAll('<div id="site-wrapper"></div>');
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance, My test page url is http://xaxis.hs-sites.com/test1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Replace that line with these ones:-

```
$('body> div').find('script:not(script[type="IN/Share"])').remove();
$('body> div:not(.body-container-wrapper)').wrapAll('<div id="site-wrapper"></div>');
```

Comment: thanks its working, actually i just edited my question and changed body-container-wrapper to header-container-wrapper,  thanks bro once again